# Simulated Sensors in latest IntelliJ+Android: onSensorChanged gets not called

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb, android-sensors

As a part of my program I have a class capturing the data produced by the accelometer-sensor.
After switching from Android Studio (1.x, don't know exactly), the `onSensorChanged`-Method is not being executed anymore (everything else works as before, no changes in the code).
Does they changed anything on how sensor events are generated?
The API says, onsensorchange is called when sensor values change.. Maybe they made the new emulation a bit too real.. How can I force a sensor-change?

Because, as before, the sensor is initialized and registered successfully (`sensor` is not null and `sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)` gives TRUE)

The Service gets called and keeps running (no onDestroy or any exception)

Edit:
Tested it with my physical android device and Sensorchanged-Method is called there! Seems like my initial assumption is correct.. Thats a bit funny.. How did they want the developers to get the sensors changed?? Shake the notebook.. maybe. stupid.

Comment: Android Studio is a development environment and code not being executed has nothing to do with a development ide. Have your checked your androidmanifest.xml file for sensor permissions ? or you could be missing a library or something.

Comment: Not the IDE but maybe the Emulators.. Do the emulated phones call onSensorChanged continuously or do they expect that the sensor-values really change?... The corresponding service is started, within the onStartCommand()-Method i successfully initialize and register the sensor.. The Service is running.. And to access the accelometer you do not need specific permissions... The onSensorChanged() is simply NOT called...